# error mvc .net core Cannot deserialize the current JSON object with api call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, .net-core, httprequest

I have an application that makes a get call to IEXTrading api. The call itself returns the data, but when I want to load it into a viewmodel to present it, it returns an error message "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object" I have created a separate viewmodel where the data should load into.

My Controller

```
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear(); 
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://cloud.iexapis.com/");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"stable/stock/aapl/quote?filter=symbol,companyName,volume,latestSource,latestPrice,latestTime&token=MY_KEY").Result;
                    var resultList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<GetQuoteAPIViewModel>>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}                
            return View(resultList);
        }
```

My Viewmodel

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class GetQuoteAPIViewModel
    {
        public IList<ApiQuote> apiQuote { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
 public class ApiQuote
    {        
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        public string LatestTime { get; set; }
        public string latestSource { get; set; }
        public int iexVolume { get; set; }
        public decimal latestPrice { get; set; }
        public System.Net.HttpStatusCode IsSuccessStatusCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My view:

```
    @model WebApplication1.Models.ViewModels.GetQuoteAPIViewModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    }
    <div>
    @foreach(var quote in Model)
    {
        @quote.latestPrice
        @quote.LatestTime
        @($"{quote.symbol}, {quote.companyName}")
        @quote.latestSource

    }
</div>
```

Apparantly, I am missing something like a convertion to a specific type. However, if I use the model directly and then use                 var `resultList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<GetQuoteAPIViewModel>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` the data gets loaded to my view. The problem then seems to be that I can't use indexing or enumerating, because it has no Enumerator.
 What is a typical .net core MVC way to solve this, including viewmodels, etc?

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: What does your view look like? Are you inheriting GetQuoteAPIViewModel?

Comment: @user10728126 I added my view, including the model I'm using

Comment: @GaryStewart If I use response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; I get a json object returned {"symbol":"BAC","companyName":"Bank of America Corp.","volume":null,"latestSource":"Close","latestPrice":27.05,"latestTime":"September 3, 2019"} . Is this what you mean?

Comment: @CMorgan Yes, so that JSON result doesn't appear to have a collection of "ApiQuote", it IS an ApiQuote ..

Comment: @GaryStewart okay, thank you, but how exactly do I proceed now?

Comment: Well, that API call you are making has a filter that looks like it scopes the result to just one company.  If you are really trying to get more than 1, then you should start there.

Comment: this: "@model WebApplication1.Models.ViewModels.GetQuoteAPIViewModel" should be this: "@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.ViewModels.GetQuoteAPIViewModel>" or: "@model List<WebApplication1.Models.ViewModels.GetQuoteAPIViewModel>"

Comment: @GaryStewart No, the JSON is correct, I don't want more than one.

Comment: @user10728126 changing the viewmodel reference did not solve it, unfortunately. Still the message about deserialization. Even if I change my viewmodel to public ApiQuote apiQuote {get; set; } (instead of public IList<ApiQuote> apiQuote {get; set; } it doesn't work.